# Verbs before the preposition "to"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, gerunds

It is well known that [preposition must be followed by a verb in -ing form](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-rule.htm#:%7E:text=A%20preposition%20cannot%20be%20followed,or%20verb%20in%20noun%20form.). I do see sentences in which it really occurs, for example,

> This is crucial **to** building a good team.

> He‘s not used **to** driving in London

However, I also see sentences where the preposition "to" is followed by a verb which is not in -ing form, for instance

> This is watered **to** grow faster... (I thought it should be "This is watered **to** grow**ing** faster..." since "to" is a preposition)

> The criteria used **to** improve performance... (I thought it should be "The criteria used **to** improv**ing** performance..." since "to" is a preposition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct usage of "to" + verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77196/correct-usage-of-to-verb)

Comment: @livresque although there is overlap, that answer does not include the answer of my question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, "to" is being used a as a preposition followed by a gerund, as you state.

In the latter case, "to" is being used as part of an infinitive, in particular an *infinitive of purpose* ([see Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinitive_of_purpose)).

This infinitive serves to indicate the purpose of an action. So "the criteria used to improve performance" means "the criteria used *for the purpose of* improving performance."

Comment: Technically this *particular* example doesn't disprove the rule that "a preposition must be followed by a verb in -ing form." Here "to" is not a preposition.

Comment: A very good source of info that complements your answer is [here](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/infinitives-of-purpose.html)

Answer (score 0):

You gave four examples:

1. This is crucial to building a good team.
2. He‘s not used to driving in London
3. This is watered to grow faster...
4. The criteria used to improve performance...

1 = This is vital to/for building a good team.
2 = He is not accustomed to driving in London.
3 = This is watered in order to grow faster...

Please note the difference between 1 and 3: in 1 'to' is placed after an adjective whereas in 3 it appears after a verb.

Please note as well the difference between 2 and 4: in 2 we have structure 'to be used to sth', but in 4 'used to' appears after a plural noun.

In 4 'used to' may be a modal (or auiliary) verb as 'I used to run a lot when I was young' denoting a past habit (mainly in BrE. See The Oxford English Grammar, p.155 4.29 Auxiliaries [11]-[13], ISBN 0-19-861250-8 or Penguim Students' Grammar of English, p.118 10.27 Used to, ISBN 0-14-080982-1).
It may also be a verb 'use' in Past Tense as in 'The hammer used to break the window ...'
Without the rest of the sentence I cannot be sure how to classify 'used to' in 4.